Use the Phong Model to determine how much red, green, and blue the user sees
I need to use the Phong model to find the rgb values at a point.
Given values:
A planar patch with endpoints at (−2, −2, 4),(0, 2, 0),(8, 4, −2) and (6, 0, 2).
A viewer at (0, 0, 6).
A white light source at (3, 6, −1), with maximum diffuse and specular components and
ambient components set at 0.1.
The point we are supposed to find the rgb values of is the center of the patch, where the center = the average of the endpoints. After I calculated this, I got p=(3,1,1).
The k values for ambient, diffuse, and specular lights are:
 red = (0.19125 0.7038 0.256777)
 green = (0.0735 0.27048 0.137622)
 blue = (0.0225 0.0828 0.086014)

alpha = 12.8
After using the complete Phong model equation, I ended up with this matrix:
-.0479
-.018
-.005
I don't understand how I could end up with negative rgb values, so I appreciate any advice!
